# Saving PDF to a Directory

Tags: python

I am having trouble saving all my created PDF's in another directory. How can i point it to save all my PDF's in the path of my choosing? I dont understand what i am doing wrong. I have my parameter set to "SavirToDir" but its not saving there. It is saving in the filename_l path.

```
import os

def makePdf(filepath_l, filename_l,SaveToDir):
        try:
            for fn in filename_l:               
                fname, fext = os.path.splitext(fn)
                newfilename = fname + ".pdf"
                im = Image.open(fname + fext)
                os.chdir(SaveToDir)
                im.save(newfilename, "PDF", resolution=100.0)
                print(f"{newfilename} created succesfully!")
                logging.info(f"{newfilename} created succesfully!")
        except Image.UnidentifiedImageError:
            print( f"{fname + fext} found. Skipping UnidentifiedImageError error because this library cannot open a .db file "
            f"and convert it to pdf.")

makePdf(filepath_l,filename_l,r'C:\Users\TEST\COA\misc.fof')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `os.path.join()`

```
def makePdf(filepath_l, filename_l,SaveToDir):
        try:
            for fn in filename_l:               
                fname, fext = os.path.splitext(fn)
                newfilename = fname + ".pdf"
                im = Image.open(fname + fext)
                os.chdir(SaveToDir)
                im.save(os.path.join(SaveToDir,newfilename),"PDF", resolution=100.0)
                print(f"{newfilename} created succesfully!")
                logging.info(f"{newfilename} created succesfully!")
        except Image.UnidentifiedImageError:
            print( f"{fname + fext} found. Skipping UnidentifiedImageError error because this library cannot open a .db file "
            f"and convert it to pdf.")

makePdf(filepath_l,filename_l,r'C:\Users\TEST\COA\misc.fof')
```